# Is it possible to show spinner/loading-msg for HTML sourced data in jQuery-DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Our server is rendering a `<table>` element with about 1000 lines of data in HTML. Client JS then initializes the DataTable from this [HTML data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html). However, on client it takes about ~3-5 second before DataTable is fully initialized and pagination is shown. During this time, full 1000 rows are rendered and visible in DOM. I didn't find it in DataTable documentation, but is there a way to show a "processing" message, or spinner while datatable in processing the dom HTML?

Such option is available of ajax or server-side-processing source, but didnt find it for HTML data source.

Comment: A spinner is probably a bad idea in this case, since the page will be lagging/freezing while initializing the DataTable, and so will the spinner. But you could perhaps show a static loading msg with an hourglass or so, just before you initialize the DataTable. Directly after that, remove the msg.

Comment: My question is why does it take so long to render that data. A thousand rows in trivial

Comment: DataTables probably creates alot of overhead and does some sorting, that might add up... I can't really tell without seeing your code.

Comment: It is possible, but it would be more interesting to see your code. It should never take 3-5 secs to generate a table with 1000 lines / rows.

Comment: https://m.datatables.net/forums/discussion/25666/how-to-customize-the-processing-message

Comment: @codneto it is possible.

Comment: can you show your code here so that we can help you out

Answer (score 1):

You have add below option in your datatable config.

```
"processing": true &   oLanguage: {sProcessing: "<div id='loader'></div>"}
```

Suppose if we consider your table id is "example".

JS code:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {

         "processing": true,
        responsive: true,
        oLanguage: {sProcessing: "<div id='loader'></div>"}
});
```

CSS for loader :

```
 #loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  margin-left:200px;
  margin-top:30px;
}
```

**Note : You have adjust css as per your datatable**

For Working example you visit below link:

**http://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/ebRXw/3302/**